# how to include net web site source files in Visual Studio project

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

i have downloaded a foreign web solution from my clients httpdoc folder.

Now i need to edit them in Visual Studio 2013/2015 but i dont know how to integrate them.

their htdocs files and folders;

```
global.asax
package.config
web.config
gruntfile.js bower.json
package.json

./app/components/account/
logincontroller.html
login.js
register.html
registercontroller.js  *and some more......)

./app/components/home/
indexcontroller
index.js 
and some more......)

./app/components/shared/ 
headercontroller.js 
header.html
more file like this......)

./app/components/
... and more folders

./app/services/ 
ajaxService.js
services.js and 
..a lot more .js files)

./app/vendors/
angular, bootstrap, jquery stuff)

./bin/
EntityFramework.dll
System.web.razor.dll  
...and  more dll's
```

For me this looks MVC like, but with a folder structure i do not understand

However, i need to edit, debug and run the sources in VS and i have no idea how to include it. Do i need to create a simple project (type?) and copy and paste or how would this work.

Can you please advice me?

Comment: Have you tried just adding the files to a new project in MVC and then running it, and then fixing any issues that appear?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question but I am guessing you have an ASP.NET MVC project using AngularjS. Right click the path from your existing project on Solution Explorer and add existing files. 
Warning: You might need to include dll files as well.

Comment: This means i need to to add the references like the EntityFramework extra because it doesnt matter if they exist in the source files, right?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mason. Probably should just add the files to an existing project.

Looks like an Angular SPA. May have no .Net aspect to it (i.e. VS just used as an editor). Just copy the files into a new VS project. If it has compiled code associated with it, it will be hard to reproduce the .Net code.

Comment: The files come from an earlier VS project and where uploaded to a webserver. Now  the clients want have added some features, means i need to edit their stuff now.

Yes, it is a SPA with angular. 
For me it looks not like MVC 4 or 5, 
It more looks like this-
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/709766/Tutorial-for-Building-SPA-using-AngularJS

Comment: If there is not a .csproj or .sln file, then you have to copy the files over to a new project or solution. See dejobo's answer for how to get the files into a new project. Henrique, not sure what you mean by not answering the question. mason, dejobo and I have answered the same. Once you get it working, please put the code in a source code repository.

Comment: CryptoSavesYou, did the uploaded files on the server include an entire project or solution (are there .proj or .sln files)?